# How many children?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My mother often has how many children?

This is what I like to call a "one-line wonder". It's a very short riddle, and there are no clues in the title. Hope you enjoy! :)

P.S. The answer is not

> "she often has children". There is a certain number of children she has, and it does not reference my actual mother.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

She has

> 10 children, because she's a "mother of ten".

Comment: Yes, jafe, getting it once again! Congratulations! Do you want to get the big green tick now or in about one-to-two days time? :)

Comment: @shoopi you should probably ROT13 that or something, just to hide it

Comment: https://www.rot13.com/

Comment: @shoopi You can't do spoilers in a comment like you can in an answer, so you  have to manually 'hide' it by encoding it, either yourself or with another website like spikey_richie posted.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something. rot13(bsgra orpbzrf bs gra)

Comment: Congratulations, jafe! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ :D